# How to search for a child key in an xml and pass it to another parent with Python/bs4?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

Here is a sample of the xml I am working with:

```
<bare>
    <key name="plus.root" value="/apps/mobile/plus"/>
    <key name="local.root" value="/apps/net/plus"/>
    <key name="slack.messaging.root" value="/apps/root/docs"/>
</bare>>
<app name="social">
    <key name="social.password" value="secret">
    <key name="user" value = "secret">
</app>
<app name="plus">
    <key name="user" value = "secret">
</app>
```

I am trying to look through each key under "bare" and if the first word matches an app name, move the key/value under the app key (as child).  So for example, plus.root would be removed from the bare section and added under the "app name=plus section".  If the app name does not exist, the key should be left alone under the bare section.

Currently my code looks like this, but I'm having trouble figuring out properly do this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")

apps = soup.find("app")
bare = soup.root.bare

# loop over all the "key's under "bare"
for key in bare.find_all("key"):
    app_name = key["name"].split(".")[0]

    # find apps that match name of the bare key
    app = apps.find("app", {"name": app_name})

    #if we find any, ???append the key to the app???? then remove the key from the bare section
    if app:
        key = key.extract()
        app.append(key)
        # remove "bare"
        bare.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean keyz.append(keyname)

Comment: is BeautifulSoup a requirement? seems like it would be simpler to use one of the dedicated xml parsing libs

Comment: it is not a requirement, i actually just switched to beautifulsoup from lxml thinking that would be easier.

Comment: i'm open to any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample to get you started. Here we are moving all of the keys under the "bare" to under a separate "apps" tag, grouping by app name:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

data = """
<root>
    <bare>
        <key name="plus.root" value="/apps/mobile/plus"/>
        <key name="local.root" value="/apps/net/plus"/>
        <key name="slack.messaging.root" value="/apps/root/docs"/>
    </bare>
    <apps/>
</root>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")

apps = soup.find("apps")
bare = soup.root.bare
# loop over all the "key"s under "bare"
for key in bare.find_all("key"):
    app_name = key["name"].split(".")[0]

    # find app and create if not exists
    app = apps.find("app", {"name": app_name})
    if not app:
        app = soup.new_tag("app")
        app.attrs["name"] = app_name
        apps.append(app)

    # remove the key from "bare" and append to a specific app
    key = key.extract()
    app.append(key)

# remove "bare"
bare.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Here is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <apps>
  <app name="plus">
   <key name="plus.root" value="/apps/mobile/plus"/>
  </app>
  <app name="local">
   <key name="local.root" value="/apps/net/plus"/>
  </app>
  <app name="slack">
   <key name="slack.messaging.root" value="/apps/root/docs"/>
  </app>
 </apps>
</root>
```

Comment: This kinddddd of helps.  I still need to figure out the logic of checking if the barekey has a matching app in the app section and if so, moving it over to the app section.

Comment: trying to figure it out now

Comment: @david I think this is already in the presented code - see the `find app and create if not exists` section..

Comment: ohhh I see.  The only thing I need to change is that a new app does not need to be created if the app doesn't exist.  in other words, if the app exists, add it, otherwise leave it in the bare section.